# Creation of a table containing multiple row instances based on the count from another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Let's say I have one table, let's called it T1. It has 100 rows.
I also have another table, let's call it T2. It has 3 rows.
I want to create another table, let's call that T3.

For each row in T2, I'd like to duplicate each row in T1 and JOIN on data from each of the T2 rows, inserting into T3. In the example above T3 would have 300 rows, structured as follows:

```
**Table 3**
T3 PK|T1 [Row 1] FK|T2(Row 1) FK
T3 PK|T1 [Row 1] FK|T2(Row 2) FK
T3 PK|T1 [Row 1] FK|T2(Row 3) FK
```

and then for the second row of T1....

```
**Table 3**
T3 PK|T1 [Row 2] FK|T2(Row 1) FK
T3 PK|T1 [Row 2] FK|T2(Row 2) FK
T3 PK|T1 [Row 2] FK|T2(Row 3) FK
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross join?

```
select
    T1.*,
    T2.*
from
    T1
    cross join T2
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't worked with cross joins before but this does the job nicely!